# Hungarian train (MÁV) tickets online?

Tags: trains, tickets, hungary

**Short version:** Can I buy tickets for Hungarian trains online somewhere?

**Long version:**
In two months, I travel from Czechia to Hungary, namely Jindřichův Hradec - Debrecen and back.
Czech Railways offer me the following tickets:

- Jindřichův Hradec - Debrecen and back for `~ EUR 120`
- Jindřichův Hradec - Budapest and back for `~ EUR 50`

This means that if I got the ticket for Budapest - Debrecen and back online for `< EUR 50`, I could save a reasonable amount of money. However, I found no e-shop on http://mav.hu/english/index.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can buy Hungarian train tickets at their [other website](http://www.mav-start.hu/english/index.php).

Comment: You gotta love such schizophrenia. Thanks a lot.